# enzyme shallow() renders differently in snapshot in my local

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, yarnpkg

My local snapshots conflict with our team's master branch when I run `yarn test` which creates/updates the snapshots, and:

1. I didn't change the source code, simply `git clone`, `yarn install`, then `yarn test`
2. Deleting yarn.lock and node_module and install again doesn't change this behavior
3. My yarn version (1.12.3), jest version (2.36.0), and enzyme version (3.8.0) are all the same as other members

I suspected it's enzyme, as it is this lib shallow renders stuff, but I am sure I have the same version for all related packages come up with `yarn list *enzyme*`

Wonder why am I getting this inconsistency. Thank you.

```
            <img
              alt=""
              className="centered-speed-dial"
              src={
                Object {

                   // In master branch
    -             "ReactComponent": [Function],  

                   // what my local try to update it to
    +             "ReactComponent": Object {
    +               "$$typeof": Symbol(react.forward_ref),  
    +               "render": [Function],
    +             },

                  "__esModule": true,
                  "default": "speed-dial.svg",
                }
              }
            />

      44 |             props.hasError = true;
      45 |             const wrapper = renderWrapper();
    > 46 |             expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
         |                                     ^
      47 |         });
      48 |     });
      49 | });
```

Comment: I assume you didn't change the source code in anyway. What kind of difference are you getting between the snapshot you have and the snapshot in the repository?

Comment: How the snapshot renders `"ReactComponent": [Function]`, I will update the post to make it clear.

Comment: I think it's more about jest pretty printing the function value or not. Perhaps `pretty-format` or something. Can you show your jest config? Are there any serializers involved etc.

Comment: That's a great point because my prettifier also behaves differently from others.  We don't have a config file for jest...It seems we just simply reply on react-script.  

`"test": "cross-env NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu react-scripts test --testURL http://localhost/xxx"`

Comment: I did `yarn clean cache` and deleted the repo to clone again to resolve the issue. Still not sure what's the exact cause, but the problem is no more.